# how to store the csv file into google cloud store bucket using web2py code

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, web2py

I got the csv file from web2py application now i have to store this same file into google cloud store bucket manually(bucket is already created in google Developers Console)through my web2py application code

Comment: I don't think your question has much to do with web2py. Your implementation for that is framework independent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you handle your stuff in web2py but to store a file in a bucket I do this:

```
def store_file(self, filename, content):
    bucket = '/' + os.environ.get('BUCKET_NAME', app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
    filename = bucket + '/' + filename.
    try:
        gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='text/plain')
        gcs_file.write(content)
        gcs_file.close()
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)
        try:
            gcs.delete(filename)
        except gcs.NotFoundError:
            logging.info("Could not delete file " + filename)
    logging.info("Created a file " + filename)
    return filename
```

The content variable in my case is from cStringIO.StringIO().getValue()

More info / example [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted)